# How can i check for ftp valid address when typing it in a textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

I have this textBox Textchanged event:

```
private void anyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnUpload.Enabled = txtHost.TextLength > 0 && txtUploadFile.TextLength > 0;
            checkBox1.Enabled = txtDir.TextLength > 0;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
```

The textBox that i type the ftp address inside is: txtHost

The ftp address already include the ftp://
The user should only enter the textBox the address only for example:

- myftp.test.com
- myftp.com
- 1.3.4.5

The problem is the user can type anything in the textBox if i will type just forexample: dfsdfsf

Then in the class that make the upload it will not be able to resolve this address:

```
using(Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
```

And it will throw exception: The remote name could not be resolved: 'dfcdfdsf'

So what i want to do in this event TextChanged is that the user will be able to type/paste only valid ftp address.

For example: 3.4.5.6 is valid ? or ftp.test.com ? What other formats are valid as ftp addresses ?
And how can i make the checking in the TextChanged event so if the user type/paste invalid format it will will throw a messageBox ?

Comment: dfsdfsf could be a valid address as well. You need to handle the error nicely but give the user all the options. If a user decides to enter dfsdfsf then he should be able to do so.

Comment: Have you tried using `Uri.TryParse` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @JamesBlond said in the commands, dfsdfsf could be a valid adress as well. 
I would advice you to let the user press a button before checking the ftp address, checking it while typing, and thus trying to make a connection to some servers, will cost you memory and your program might run slower because it repeatedly executes that `requestStream` code.

What you could do is use [regex](http://www.regexr.com/) to exclude some characters that will never be used for a ftp address.

If you really want to check it while typing, don't check it on every TextChanged event, so wait about one to two seconds before checking a address. (can be done with a timer).